# Changing the values of sliced numpy array doesn't change the original data in it

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have a numpy array `total_weights` which is an `IxI` array of floats. Each row/columns corresponds to one of `I` items.

During my main loop I acquire another real float array `weights` of size `NxM` (`N, M < I`) where each/column row also corresponds to one of the original `I` items (duplicates may also exist).

I want to add this array to `total_weights`. However, the sizes and order of the two arrays are not aligned. Therefore, I maintain a position map, a pandas Series with an index of item IDs to their proper index/position in `total_weights`, called `pos_df`.

In order to properly make the addition I want I perform the following operation inside the loop:

```
candidate_pos = pos_df.loc[candidate_IDs]     # don't worry about how I get these
rated_pos = pos_df.loc[rated_IDs]             # ^^
total_weights[candidate_pos, :][:, rated_pos] += weights
```

Unfortunately, the above operation must be editing a copy of the orignal `total_weights` matrix and not a view of it, since after the loop the `total_weights` array is still full of zeroes. How do I make it change the original data?

Edit:
I want to clarify that candidate_IDs are the `N` IDs of items and `rated_IDs` are the `M` IDs of items in the `NxM` array called `weights`. Through `pos_df` I can get their total order in all of `I` items.

Also, my guess as to the reason a copy is returned is that `candidate_IDs` and thus `candidate_pos` will probably contain duplicates e.g. `[0, 1, 3, 1, ...]`. So the same rows will sometimes have to be pulled into the new array/view.

Comment: Whether `total_weights[candidate_pos, :][:, rated_pos]` returns a copy or a view depends on what `candidate_pos` and `rate_pos` actually are. Fancy indexing (e.g. using an array of integers as index) always returns copies. I suggest you to elaborate a little more about your indices `candidate_pos` and `rate_pos`, so to make easier to provide you with a solution...also because your actual usage of the indexing looks quite cumbersome to me.

Comment: I added a clarification about the IDs and their positions as well as why I think I get served with a copy. There may be another solution but it has to work with `pos_df` in order to properly align the two matrices in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is in how you are using indexing. As `candidate_pos` is an array, `total_weights[candidate_pos, :]` is a fancy indexing operation that returns a new array. When you apply indexing again, i.e. `...[:, rated_pos]` you are assigning elements to the newly created array rather than to `total_weights`.

The second problem, as you have already spotted, is in the actual logic you are trying to apply. If I understand your example correctly, you have a `I x I` matrix with weights, and you want to update weights for a sequence of pairs `((Ix_1, Iy_1), ..., (Ix_N, Iy_N))` with repetitions, with a single line of code. This can't be done in this way, using `+=` operator, as you'll find yourself having added to `weights[Ix_n, Iy_n]` the weight corresponding to the last time `(Ix_n, Iy_n)` appears in your sequence: you have to first merge all the repeating elements in your sequence of weight updates, and then perform the update of your `weights` matrix with the new "unique" sequence of updates. Alternatively, you must collect your `weights` as an `I x I` matrix, and directly sum it to `total_weights`.

Comment: Oh my god, you re right about the second issue.. it can't be done at once..

Answer (score 0):

After @rveronese pointed out that it's impossible to do it one go because of the duplicates in candidate_pos I believe I have managed to do what I want with a for-loop on them:

```
candidate_pos = pos_df.loc[candidate_IDs]     # don't worry about how I get these
rated_pos = pos_df.loc[rated_IDs]             # ^^
for i, c in enumerate(candidate_pos):
     total_weights[c, rated_pos] += weights[i, :]
```

In this case, the indexing does not create a copy and the assignment should be working as expected...